# iOS : How to make TableView not to fill the height?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xib

I've created a tableview, in the xib editor of the xcode. I've positioned the table view in the middle of the screen, it starts somewhere in the middle (100 pt. form the top) and should end a little bit lower (it's total height is 200 pt.). But when I run it on the simulator it fills the height of the TableView until the bottom of the screen.

Sorry for the nooby question. I'm just starting with iOS after years of java.

Screensot[image]

Comment: set the frame of you table view using its outlet and cgrectmake method.

Comment: Can provide some code or can tell how you did this from programming or interface builder??

Comment: yourTableviewOutlet.frame=CGRectMake(0,100,320,200);  put this in view did load.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the interface builder?

Comment: yes in your own image where it says frame rectange there are values for x,y,width ,height set them

Comment: @amar How do I get the instance of the tableView? It was added in the interface builder

Comment: Please test this on iPhone5 Screen. Your viewController is of size of iPhone5 screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Size inspector tab. and remove the bottom resize from xib just like this screenshot

[image]

Just go to file inspector tab and disable (un-checked) the *Use Autolayout*

[image]

Comment: I don't habe this option, you can see the screenshot I've added

Comment: That is because you are using 'autolayout'.  In your xib , go to the right side panel and select the first tab 'File Inspector'. Select your main view and you will see a checked option called 'use Autolayout' . Uncheck that and you will have these options. Cheers!